# opencvでの動画ファイルエッジ検出後の保存方法

Tags: python, opencv

opencvの使い方で分からないことがあります。

元の動画ファイルをopencvでエッジ検出させ、新たに動画ファイルとして保存したいと思い、
以下のコードで実行しようとしました。

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

fps    = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', int(fourcc), fps, (int(width), int(height)))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        edge = cv2.Canny(frame,50,100)
        out.write(edge)
        cv2.imshow('frame',edge)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    except:
        break

out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

動画ファイルは出力されますが、中身が再生できません。
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

一旦フレーム毎の画像に切り出して画像をフレーム毎につなげることで動画にできました。
以下参考にしてください。
またこちらの動画をエッジ処理に使いました。
[利用した動画](http://www.cellstat.net/aerial/)

```
import cv2
import glob
import re
import os

INPUT_FILE_NAME = "aerial.mp4"
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "output.m4v"

# ソートされた連番の画像ファイルパスを取得できます
def numerical_sort(value):
    numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts


def convert_video_2_images():
    # 元ビデオファイル読み込み
    org = cv2.VideoCapture(INPUT_FILE_NAME)
    i = 0
    if not os.path.exists("./images"):
        os.mkdir("./images")
    while org.isOpened():
        end_flag, frame = org.read()
        edge = cv2.Canny(frame, 100, 200)
        if not end_flag:
            break
        save_file = "./images/img_{}.png".format(i)
        cv2.imwrite(save_file, edge)
        print("Save...{}".format(save_file))
        i += 1
    org.release()


def convert_images_2_video():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
    output = cv2.VideoWriter(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                             fourcc,
                             30,
                             (1280, 720))

    for img_file in sorted(glob.glob("images/*.png"), key=numerical_sort):
        img = cv2.imread(img_file)
        output.write(img)
    output.release()

def main():
    convert_video_2_images()
    convert_images_2_video()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```